# Sorting XMLTag using XSL Stylesheet Java Transformer Factory

Tags: java, xml, sorting, xslt

I have below XML file that i would like to sort it in specific way. Basically XMLTags will be sorted alphabatically first and then within each XMLtag, one of the XMLelement will be used to sort them alphabetically also. Please see the current XML and the final result that i am required

Original XML

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Profile xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
<applicationVisibilities>
    <application>Test</application>
    <default>true</default>
    <visible>true</visible>
</applicationVisibilities>
<classAccesses>
    <apexClass>TestClass</apexClass>
    <enabled>false</enabled>
</classAccesses>
<applicationVisibilities>
    <application>Class</application>
    <default>true</default>
    <visible>false</visible>
</applicationVisibilities>
<classAccesses>
    <apexClass>FooClass</apexClass>
    <enabled>false</enabled>
</classAccesses>
<fieldPermissions>
    <editable>false</editable>
    <field>Hello</field>
    <readable>true</readable>
</fieldPermissions>
<applicationVisibilities>
    <application>Foo</application>
    <default>true</default>
    <visible>false</visible>
</applicationVisibilities>
<fieldPermissions>
    <editable>false</editable>
    <field>Blah</field>
    <readable>true</readable>
</fieldPermissions>
</Profile>
```

Final Output

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Profile xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
<applicationVisibilities>
    <application>Class</application>
    <default>true</default>
    <visible>false</visible>
</applicationVisibilities>
<applicationVisibilities>
    <application>Foo</application>
    <default>true</default>
    <visible>false</visible>
</applicationVisibilities>
<applicationVisibilities>
    <application>Test</application>
    <default>true</default>
    <visible>true</visible>
</applicationVisibilities>
 <classAccesses>
    <apexClass>FooClass</apexClass>
    <enabled>false</enabled>
</classAccesses>
<classAccesses>
    <apexClass>TestClass</apexClass>
    <enabled>false</enabled>
</classAccesses>
<fieldPermissions>
    <editable>false</editable>
    <field>Blah</field>
    <readable>true</readable>
</fieldPermissions>
<fieldPermissions>
    <editable>false</editable>
    <field>Hello</field>
    <readable>true</readable>
</fieldPermissions>
</Profile>
```

Once the tags are sorted then for each of those tags, i would use specific element to sort them. Example: applicaitonVisibilities tag will be sorted alphabetically using application xmlelement value. For classAccesses, apexClass will be used for sorting alphabatically and lastly for fieldPermissions, field element will be used for sorting. I was playing around with the current XSL stylesheet but it's not working.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Profile/applicationVisibilities">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="application">
            <xsl:sort select="node()" data-type="text" order="ascending" />
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

My current java code for using the current XSL

```
XSL   TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer(new StreamSource(new File("profile.xsl")));
    //transformerFactory.setAttribute("indent-number", 10);
    transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
    transformer.setOutputProperty("{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", "4");
    transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.METHOD, "xml");
    transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "no");
    transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "UTF-8");
    DOMSource source = new DOMSource(document);
    StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File(originalFile));
    transformer.transform(source, result);
```

Comment: JAXP is a JRE/JDK API that on the one hand with the built-in processor only supports XSLT 1 but on the other hand in the Java world can be easily used with Saxon 10 or 9 to have XSLT 2 or 3 support. Are you able to put e.g. Saxon 10 HE on the class path?

Comment: Yes i can put saxon in the classpath. Please provide me with the version#.

Comment: Saxon HE 10.3 is the current release.

Comment: Saxon 10 HE is available on Sourceforge https://sourceforge.net/projects/saxon/files/Saxon-HE/10/Java/ or on Maven.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In XSLT 3 with higher-order function support (Saxon 10 or later all editions, Saxon 9.8 and 9.9 PE and EE, Saxon-JS 2) you could use grouping on the node-name to then sort the groups based on a map from the name to a function selecting the child element:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xpath-default-namespace="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">
    
  <xsl:param name="sort-keys"
    as="map(xs:QName, function(*))"
    select="map {
              QName('http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata', 'applicationVisibilities') : function($el) { $el/application }, 
              QName('http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata', 'classAccesses') : function($el) { $el/apexClass },
              QName('http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata', 'fieldPermissions') : function($el) { $el/field } 
            }"/>

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/*">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-by="node-name()">
              <xsl:sort select="string(current-grouping-key())"/>
              <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()">
                  <xsl:sort select="$sort-keys(node-name())(.)"/>
              </xsl:apply-templates>
          </xsl:for-each-group>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

In earlier versions you could use

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xpath-default-namespace="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/*">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-by="node-name()">
              <xsl:sort select="current-grouping-key() => string()"/>
              <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()">
                  <xsl:sort select="if (. instance of element(applicationVisibilities))
                                    then application
                                    else if (. instance of element(classAccesses))
                                    then apexClass
                                    else if (. instance of element(fieldPermissions))
                                    then field
                                    else ()"/>
              </xsl:apply-templates>
          </xsl:for-each-group>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

A (hopefully) pure XSLT 2 version of that would be

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xpath-default-namespace="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="2.0">

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/*">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-by="node-name(.)">
              <xsl:sort select="string(current-grouping-key())"/>
              <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()">
                  <xsl:sort select="if (. instance of element(applicationVisibilities))
                                    then application
                                    else if (. instance of element(classAccesses))
                                    then apexClass
                                    else if (. instance of element(fieldPermissions))
                                    then field
                                    else ()"/>
              </xsl:apply-templates>
          </xsl:for-each-group>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks for posting. I changed the code to use SAXON transofrmer factory and added this XSL stylesheet but i am getting bunch of errors. TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance("net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl",null);Error at xsl:param on line 14 column 18 of profile.xsl:
  XPST0003: XPath syntax error at char 0 on line 14 in {map {               QName}:
    Node constructor expressions are allowed only in XQuery, not in XPath
Error at xsl:param on line 14 column 18 of profile.xsl:

Comment: @darkest, I can't explain that error message unless it comes from a version of Saxon predating XSLT 3 like Saxon 9.7 or older perhaps. Anyway, I added a less flexible but more compatible alternative to the sorting based on the element name.

Comment: I am using saxon 9.1.8 but still getting a error. I tried with the earlier version you posted but got a different error :Error at xsl:for-each-group on line 13 column 65 of profile.xsl:
  XPST0017: XPath syntax error at char 11 on line 13 in {node-name()}:
    Function node-name() must have 1 argument
Error at xsl:sort on line 14 column 70 of profile.xsl:

Comment: I posted XSLT 3 code assuming at least Saxon 9.8. For such an old version like 9.1 I think with only XSLT 2 support you need two changes, i.e. `group-by="node-name(.)"` instead of `group-by="node-name()"` and then `select="string(current-grouping-key())"` instead of `select="current-grouping-key() => string()"`

Comment: And you would need to drop the `xsl:mode` declaration and instead keep the first `xsl:template` from your posted code.

Comment: Tried the changes but received an error Error at xsl:for-each-group on line 13 column 65 of profile.xsl:
  XPST0017: XPath syntax error at char 11 on line 13 in {node-name()}:
    Function node-name() must have 1 argument

Comment: I think it would be easier for you to upgrade to Saxon HE 10 than for me to remember all the pesky details to downgrade my XSLT 3 approach to XSLT 2 compatiblity. But one of the changes I already put in a comment is to use `group-by="node-name(.)"` where the `node-name(.)` call has the argument `.` so if you haven't done that already then you need to fix that.

Comment: I added saxonhe9.4 in classpath but now receiving this error : Exception in thread "main" net.sf.saxon.trans.LicenseException: Requested feature (XSLT 3.0) requires Saxon-PE

Comment: Yea unfortunately i cannot upgrade to use XSL3 :\

Comment: As I said, the code is XSLT 3, as far as I can tell the second sample should work with Saxon 9.8 or later all editions, the first sample with Saxon 10 or later all editions. I have made several suggestions in the comments to rewrite XPath 3.1 expressions as XPath 2.0 ones that should allow the code to be used with any XSLT 2 processor like Saxon 8.9 to 9.7.

Comment: Thanks man. Finally it works !. I appreciate your help. Is there a way to set the identation to may be 4 spaces ? Currently the XMLTAG is set to 3 spaces & XMLElement is set to 8. I would like to set the XMLTAG to 4 spaces

Comment: A consistent indentation is usually achieved by having both `<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>` and `<xsl:output indent="yes"/>`. The exact amount of indentation is processor dependent, whether/how an old version of Saxon allows setting that from Java I don't know, I would suggest to ask that as a new, separate questions if the documentation of the old release on Sourceforge doesn't bring up anything.